Google Directory API - 403 [Not Authorized to access this resource/api] for Method: roles.list
I am using Google Directory API .NET Client to fetch a list of roles in a domain (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/roles/list).
I use a service account to authenticate on behalf of a user to create the Directory Service.
Here is my code:
var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    ApplicationName = "GoogleConnector",
    HttpClientInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(connectionDetails.ClientEmail) { User = connectionDetails.UserId, Scopes = scopes }.FromPrivateKey(connectionDetails.PrivateKey)
    )
};

var service = new DirectoryService(initializer);
var roles = await service.Roles.List("my_customer").ExecuteAsync();

Now, it works fine without any issues when the user being used for impersonation has a Super Admin role assigned to it. However, providing a Super Admin role to this user is not feasible.
When I remove the Super Admin role, assign the following roles:

User Management
Groups Reader
Service Admin


Also, the next request scopes have been added:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.rolemanagement
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.rolemanagement.readonly

The api starts failing with the below error:
Not Authorized to access this resource/
api [403] Errors [ Message[Not Authorized to access this resource/api] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global] ]

EDIT (after the comment about missing delegation to a domain user)
I have provided domain-wide delegation to the client application (since I am using a service account, following the guide) with all the required scopes:

Also, all other API works fine. I am using groups.list and users.list methods without any issues. Those return the results as usual.
The issue only is with the roles.list method.
Any help is appreciated.

Can you share in your post the scopes that you used? May I confirm if you used these two: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.rolemanagement and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.rolemanagement.readonly (Based from the article)?

Thank you @Gyul. Those scopes have been added. I will include it in my question.

You are missing delegation to a domain user

Thx, @LindaLawton-DaImTo, I've tried it (but unfortunately the result is the same =/). The original post has been updated.

Try the sample i posted

You need to pass the full credentials.json as well as an admin user with access.   This is my sample for creating a user you should just be able to change the scope and the method it calls.
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1;
using Google.Apis.Services;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, Google Calendar Workspace sample!");

var scopes = new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser };

const string workspaceAdmin = "admin@mydomain.com";

const string credentials = @"C:\Development\Credentials\workspaceserviceaccount.json";

var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(credentials).CreateScoped(scopes).CreateWithUser(workspaceAdmin);

var services = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
});

var request = services.Users.List();
request.Customer = "my_customer";
request.MaxResults = 10;
request.OrderBy = UsersResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.Email;
    
var results = request.Execute();

var users = results.UsersValue;

if (users.Count == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No Users");
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine("Users:");
foreach (var user in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{user.PrimaryEmail} ({user.Name.FullName})");
}


an admin user with access -> What do you mean by this? Does the user need to have Super Admin role? If so, this is not possible for us to provide. What roles does this user need in order to be able to fetch the list of roles?

they need to have access to list users.    If your logging in as a service account just have the service account impersonate the admin user on the domain.  I would start with users - read

What is the meaning of "admin user on the domain" here? How do we define admin user?
Linds, Suppose I have User A in my domain, and this User A is NOT a Super Admin but have User Management role in Google Workspace.
The service account is impersonating this User A to list the roles (NOT list users), but this doesn't work.

From what i can see in your code they are not impersonating the user  you need to use .CreateWithUser(workspaceAdmin) as I have.

Well, I am using a different approach to creating a credential, and it takes the UserId parameter to impersonate the user:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fOghwxuGTDULR_-sYlEBKJUDWvcMoJrr/view?usp=sharing
Also, just to be clear, I have many other APIs which are working just fine with this approach, I am facing issue with only one particular API (roles.list)

where in the documentation does it say you can use the UserId parm to impersonate a user?

I followed this document[https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service-account] to create ServiceAccountCredentials and then followed the details here[https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Auth/latest/api/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer.html#Google_Apis_Auth_OAuth2_ServiceAccountCredential_Initializer_User]  to find out how we can pass the User Id
